# programmatically print name of Rproject I am working in

Tags: r

I can programmatically extract and save the name of my project by assuming that the project name is the last string after "/" in the file path generated by here::here().

```
  here::here() %>% stringr::str_extract("[^/]*$")
```

Is there a safer way to access the project name programmatically? Something like `project.name()`, which is a make-believe function?

Comment: That does not answer your question but you might use `basename()` instead of `stringr::str_extract("[^/]*$")`. Also `getwd()` might be helpful for you.

Comment: @markus basename() is very useful for this. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for `rstudioapi::getActiveProject()`.